# How can I compress ASCII art into RLE with run lengh of 2 (or decompress RLE into ascii in the same way)?

Tags: python

I want to get a program or a function to compress ASCII art from a text file into RLE with a run length of 2, so it counts the amount of characters and displays it like so: `04662312x52c02z01 03a` (just an example), so that it takes 2 numbers then a character.

```
from collections import OrderedDict 
def runLengthEncoding(input): 
    dict=OrderedDict.fromkeys(input, 0) 
    for ch in input: 
        dict[ch] += 1
    for key,value in dict.iteritems(): 
         output = output + key + str(value) 
    return output
```

Ive tried this code but it doesnt work for number characters (it reads `53405211c` as `"53405211", "c"` instead of `"53", "4" "05", "2"  "11", "c"`)

If anyone could simplify this

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] ? What have you tried so far? What problems have you found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see how your code is supposed to split the string into groups of 2+1 character, but anyway, using a `dict` or `OrderedDict` would not work, as even if ordered, a `dict` can hold any key at most once, i.e. it could not represent an encoded string like `01a01b01a`. Instead, you should create a list of tuples, and you can do so using just string slicing and a `range` with `step=3`:

```
def runLengthEncoding(s):
    return [(int(s[i:i+2]), s[i+2]) for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]

>>> runLengthEncoding("04662312x52c02z01 03a")
[(4, '6'), (62, '3'), (12, 'x'), (52, 'c'), (2, 'z'), (1, ' '), (3, 'a')]
```

It is not really clear from your question whether the function is supposed to encode or decode the strings, but judging from your final sentence, I assume you want to decode them. The other direction can easily be done with `itertools.groupby` and some `str.join`ing:

```
# RLE -> Text
s = "04662312x52c02z01 03a"
pairs = [(int(s[i:i+2]), s[i+2]) for i in range(0, len(s), 3)]
# [(4, '6'), (62, '3'), (12, 'x'), (52, 'c'), (2, 'z'), (1, ' '), (3, 'a')]
text = ''.join(n * c for n, c in pairs)
# '666633333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333xxxxxxxxxxxxcccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccczz aaa'

# Text -> RLE
from itertools import groupby
pairs = [(len(list(g)), k) for k, g in groupby(text)]
# [(4, '6'), (62, '3'), (12, 'x'), (52, 'c'), (2, 'z'), (1, ' '), (3, 'a')]
s = ''.join("%02d%s" % (n, c) for n, c in pairs)
# '04662312x52c02z01 03a'
```